# How do I remap a set of hotkeys only when a certain window is in focus?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gtk, gtk3

Is there a way to remap keys on the keyboard to an alternative configuration on a window-by-window basis?

I don't know how it works on Linux but on Windows I can detect a window by its title and class name with FindWindow(), test that against GetForegroundWindow(), and then RegisterHotKey() to change the key.

How can I do something similar on Linux?

I'm running MATE Desktop on Fedora 30 so it's all GTK3.

Comment: The Window Manager can do this: It gets all the focus events, and it also can process additional hotkeys. It's easy to configure this in `fvwm`, for example. The application library (GTK) has no influence on this. I have no idea if the MATE Desktop Window Manager can do this, however, as I don't use the MATE Desktop.

Comment: For MATE the window manager is `marco` (forked from `metacity`).

Comment: From the metacity manpage: "metacity lacks some features that may be expected by traditional UNIX or other technical users; these users may want to investigate other available window managers for use with GNOME or standalone."